# Javascript button filtering show another div on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, filter

I'm using button filtering from this website:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/portfolio-gallery-with-filtering-category

Is it possible to let it automatically open 'HDPE Pipes' instead of 'All'?
I hope someone here can provide me an answer because I'm really stuck here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### X2 primary concerns to address:

**1. Hide the `.filter` elements that are not `.hdpe` so that they don't display on page load**

Since you are using `.hide()` and `.show()` methods respectively to toggle between the display of elements in question, stick with an *inline* style rule (`style="display: none;"`) that you should declare on all `.figure` elements that do not have the class `.hdpe` - so in other words; "all elements you don't want to have show up on page load", e.g:

```
<!-- You want to have displayed on page load -->
<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
  <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<!-- You don't want to have displayed on page load -->
<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle" style="display: none;">
  <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

**2. Add the `.active` class to the `.filter-button` element you want to have *active* on page load**

You'll need to also account for the filter button that *should be active on page load*. Add the class `.active` to the `.filter-button` element in question, in this case that would be element with the attribute `data-filter="hdpe"`, e.g:

```
<div align="center">
  <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default filter-button active" data-filter="hdpe">HDPE Pipes</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">Sprinkle Pipes</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="spray">Spray Nozzle</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="irrigation">Irrigation Pipes</button>
</div>
```

#### Code Snippet Demonstration:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".filter-button").click(function(){
    
        $(".filter-button").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        
        var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        
        if(value == "all") {
            //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.filter').show('1000');
        } else {
            //$('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
            //$(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
            $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
            $(".filter").filter('.'+value).show('3000');
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
.gallery-title
{
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #42B32F;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.gallery-title:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 7.5%;
    left: 46.5%;
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e;
}
.filter-button
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #42B32F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #42B32F;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.filter-button:hover
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #42B32F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #42B32F;

}
.btn-default:active .filter-button:active
{
    background-color: #42B32F;
    color: white;
}

.port-image
{
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery_product
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="gallery-title">Gallery</h1>
    </div>

    <div align="center">
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button active" data-filter="hdpe">HDPE Pipes</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">Sprinkle Pipes</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="spray">Spray Nozzle</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="irrigation">Irrigation Pipes</button>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle" style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice touch on the active there :)

Comment: @Highdef Thanks man - I prefer the way you approached the whole "hiding and showing" what you need to. A much more simple and elegant method.

Comment: Haha, thanks mate :) But I gotta say, I like how you 're descriptive and precise in your answers, though many people really don't appreciate that and just want a working solution.

Comment: @Highdef True. Although, I find, in some cases, the OP does appreciate the explanation as well. For this reason I strive on. And seeing positive feedback from fellow trusted site users, like yourself, is a motivating factor to write the kind of answer that would benefit other users (and the community as a whole), experiencing similar issues. And some of these users may be at liberty to know the "how" and "why" of an issue as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid point. I do have come across certain OP who are in need of explanation of every line or changes made, it shows that atleast they are trying to make an effort to understand the concept and functionality behind it.

Comment: @Highdef Which is great, because it means they *actually learn* something :) Seeing the phrase "that make sense, I get it", or something similar, can feel more rewarding than those good karma points :) (the only thing better is a combination of the two)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! A nice touch on the active indeed. Big thanks to you two for saving my day haha :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add these two lines at the beginning of your JQuery code:

```
$(".filter").not('.hdpe').hide();
$('.filter').filter('.hdpe').show();
```

This ensures that after the document is loaded, all the filters which don't have the class of hdpe are hidden and the ones which have are shown.

Here's a snippet for that:

https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/5MBWR

Comment: @stangielen2 Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted (the best way you could possibly convey your appreciation for the solution given here on SO ;)